# Turn off all CSS styles at once in dev tools

Tags: css, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug an issue with CSS and want to start experimenting with all styles turned off. Is there a way in Google Chrome devtools, Firebug or any other dev tool to turn off all styles at once, so that I can start turning them on one by one to see how it affects the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Use an add on called "Web Developer". It's available for different browsers and available here:

http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

You can disable styles from there. It even has many more features.

Comment: I tried out Web Developer add on but even though disabling all CSS was easy, I failed to find a way to start turning on the individual CSS styles. It appears not to be possible with that add-on.

Comment: Little late to the party but you could also use "Stylish" (A plugin) and then add your own custom styles to that domain for testing once you've disabled global styles through web developer toolbar.